# Linear optimization or Constraint Satisfaction Problem with food

Tags: optimization, constraint-satisfaction

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in terms of what type of problem I am describing here so I can research it.  My initial thought is that it is some form of Constraint Satisfaction Problem.

Say as an example I am working with food, and I would like to determine from a massive database of recipes which foods might sum up to equal a certain macro-nutrient profile.

For example, maybe I want to target a 410 calorie meal consisting of 30 grams of protein (4 cals per gram), 10 grams of fat (9 cals per gram) , and 50 grams of carbohydrates (4 cals per gram).

Would this be in the domain of CSP, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124642/755

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Suppose you have $n$ recipes.  Introduce zero-or-one variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, with the idea that $x_i=1$ represents including the $i$th recipe and $x_i=0$ represents omitting it.  Now you can obtain a bunch of linear equations, one per macronutrient requirement.  For instance, in your example, we get something like $c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n = 30$, where $c_i$ is the number of grams of protein contributed by the $i$th recipe.  Feed this to an off-the-shelf ILP solver, and hopefully it will find a solution for you.

If you're willing to eat multiple servings of a single recipe, you can relax the constraint on each $x_i$ and require it to be an arbitrary non-negative integer ($x_i \ge 0$), instead of requiring that it be 0 or 1.

Your problem is basically a multi-dimensional subset sum problem.  That's a special case of [the multi-dimensional knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem), which is NP-hard.  There  have been people who have studied algorithms for the multi-dimensional knapsack problem, but my guess is that the pragmatic solution is to start by trying an off-the-shelf ILP solver, and studying the literature only if that doesn't work.

---

Related: [2 Dimensional Subset Sum: looking for information](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45718/755).  Also, your problem has been proved to be NP-hard if we allow the requirements to include large numbers: [What algorithms exist for solving natural number linear systems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/26206/755). (In technical terms, the problem is NP-hard when the macro-nutrient requirements and properties are provided in binary.  I don't know if it remains NP-hard when they're provided in unary -- and the latter seems more relevant for practical situations.)